# C# Notice when a key is pressed

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts

Hello I am doing a program that will notice when a specific key is pressed and write an specific letter where the person is writing.
But i have a problem, it is that i not want to be needing to have the program as the "maked one". instead  I do want it to trigger and write out a spesifick letter or text where the user is writing as the user is pressing the key...

I hope you understand and thanks for all help

here's the code i get so far:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
            cki = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine(cki.Key.ToString());

            if (cki.Key.ToString() == "A" && (cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);
                TSendKeys.SendWait("ø");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: All this you want to be happening in console only, right?

Comment: You want all keyboard input to be processed by your app?

Comment: By not "marked one", you want this program to run in the background, capture keystrokes in a different active application, like a keylogger?  Please see if the following link will help you: [Keylogger in VB.NET](http://revolt.hyperhub.info/blog.php?action=read&item=15).

Answer (score 0):

> But i have a problem, it is that i not want to be needing to have the
>   program as the "maked one". instead I do want it to trigger and write
>   out a spesifick letter or text where the user is writing as the user
>   is pressing the key...

Reading this I think you're talking about [Windows Hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). 
This means that user prints something in another application, let's say `Word`, but you're able to catch that key (even if it wasn't pressed in your app). If this is what you actually want, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) CodeProject article is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to use a hook, [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx) explains how to do this in detail

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to emulate the behavior of Console.ReadLine, while in actuality reading and outputting each character separately.  When reading special sequences, such as CTRL+A, the behavior can be intercepted and character inserted.  A basic implementation is below.

```
private static string EmulateReadLine()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int pos = 0;
    Action<int> SetPosition = (i) =>
        {
            i = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(sb.Length, i));
            pos = i;
            Console.CursorLeft = i;
        };
    Action<char, int> SetLastCharacter = (c, offset) =>
        {
            Console.CursorLeft = sb.Length + offset;
            Console.Write(c);
            Console.CursorLeft = pos;
        };
    ConsoleKeyInfo key;
    while ((key = Console.ReadKey(true)).Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        int length = sb.Length;
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
        {
            SetPosition(pos - 1);
        }
        else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
        {
            SetPosition(pos + 1);
        }
        else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        {
            if (pos == 0) continue;
            sb.Remove(pos - 1, 1);
            SetPosition(pos - 1);
        }
        else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Delete)
        {
            if (pos == sb.Length) continue;
            sb.Remove(pos, 1);
        }
        else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Home)
            SetPosition(0);
        else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.End)
            SetPosition(int.MaxValue);
        else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            SetPosition(0);
            sb.Clear();
        }
        // CUSTOM LOGIC FOR CTRL+A
        else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.A &&
            (key.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0)
        {
            string stringtoinsert = "^";
            sb.Insert(pos, stringtoinsert);
            SetPosition(pos + stringtoinsert.Length);
        }
        else if (key.KeyChar != '\u0000') // keys that input text
        {
            sb.Insert(pos, key.KeyChar);
            SetPosition(pos + 1);
        }

        // replace entire line with value of current input string
        Console.CursorLeft = 0;
        Console.Write(sb.ToString());
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Math.Max(0, length - sb.Length)));
        Console.CursorLeft = pos;
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

To drive:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = EmulateReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Entered {0}", input);
}
```

When entering the line, pressing CTRL+A will insert the "^" character.  Arrow keys, Escape, Home, and End should function as they do normally for Console.ReadLine.  (To simplify the code, the custom insertion logic is hardwired in.)